# Excel : Automated hyperlinking to another Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns, one automatically generated (Column B), the other(Column D) with few manual values from automated generated column .

```
B           D
--------------------
1  Col1    Col2
2  12       14
3  13       16 
4  14
5  15
6  16
--------------------
```

I want to automatically Hyperlink Column D, when i enter a new row value in it.
e.g.  The entry D2 should be =HYPERLINK("#B4", B4)

Now i can calculate B4 with INDEX & MATCH, but how do i automatically hyperlink it? That is to say, if i enter 14 in D2, it should automatically get replaced by =HYPERLINK("#B4, B4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an event procedure **Worksheet_Change**: see this [article on ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm) or [this one on Chip Pearson's website](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx).

Something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   'Do nothing if more than one cell is changed or content deleted
   If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
   'Trigger the procedure only for the column D
   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
     'Turn off ALL events so the Target change does not trigger another time this sub
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      'Change the formula for what you ever want
       Target.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""#B4"", B4)"
      'Turn events back on
      Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If
End Sub
```

You just have to change the formula you want to build.